# Filter links by those that do not belong to images

Tags: javascript

I'm appending a new `div` to all image links as follows:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {    
    var divLink = document.createElement("div");
    divLink.style.position = "absolute";
    divLink.style.top = "10px";
    divLink.style.right = "10px";
    divLink.style.zIndex="1";
    divLink.style.fontSize = "20px";
    divLink.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    divLink.style.color = 'white';
    divLink.innerHTML = linkCount;
    images[i].parentNode.insertBefore(divLink, images[i] );
}
```

The above code will add the new divLink attribute to the following HTML:

```
<li>
<div>
<a title="Free Shipping" href="http://www.url.com/cp/School-Uniforms" onclick="s_objectID="http://www.url.com/cp/School-Uniforms/">
<img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://i9.url.com/images/Site/Apparel.jpg" alt="Free Shipping">
</a>
</div>
<div class="cat1">Apparel</div>
<div class="cat2">
<a title="Free Shipping" href="http://www.url.com/cp/School-Uniforms" onclick="s_objectID="http://www.url.com/cp/School-Uniforms">Free Shipping</a>
</div>
</li>
```

I now need to append a similar element to all the text links that do not belong to an image. I know that I can find all links using:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

How can I separate the links that have images, and only select links that do not belong to an image so that the attribute I'm adding doesn't get added twice to links with images.

Comment: can you use jQuery or another JS library? Any reason to require plain JS?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your html? What do you mean by `links with images`?

Comment: ...onclick="s_objectID="http://www.url.com/cp/School-Uniforms/"... is not valid HTML.

Comment: Added the html for the images Im currently adding the divLink attribute to. I need to add a similar attribute to all links that are text only and not linked to an image.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the non 'image links' Like `.standardLink` and get them using:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".standardLink");
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var links = $(".standardLink");
```

And then iterate over the array doing whatever you want with them:

```
for (i in links){
    doSomethingToThisLink(links[i]);
}
```